# Unexpectedly found nil when attempting to unwrap -- logging shows the object exists

Tags: swift

I'm breakpointing and doing print out in the lldb console and I can call methods on the object.

But when I pass to my view controller init, this unexpectedly crashes:

```
let taskVC = TaskViewController(task: task)
```

that init is:

```
convenience init(task: task) {
    self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    self.task = task
}
```

why is this happening when the task is not nil?

Comment: You need to show us how you call the VC init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
convenience init(task: task) {
    // NOT THIS -> self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    self.task = task
}
```

Comment: Convenience inits can't call super inits... they must delegate to self.